# Get email address in from Google Forms in script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm creating a Google Form where guests can log in and an email will be automatically be sent to the person that submits their form. They are not required to log into Google as this will be running on a kiosk. I have enabled the "Collect email addresses" in the settings and the field was automatically added.

The issue I am having is collecting the email address in Google Script. I have tried FormResponses, getEmail(), and getRespondentEmail() but none have worked.

```
//var UserEmail = ItemResponses[0].getResponse();
//var UserEmail = getEmail`();
var UserEmail = Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
```

Editors NOTE: From an OP's comment

> I am collecting the respondents email in a field in the form. The field was added after I enabled the "Collect email addresses" setting for the form. I am using a G Suite account; however, I do not want to have anyone log into the form as this will be on a public kiosk. Sorry I forgot to add the code for `getRespondentEmail()`. I am using it like so
>
> ```
> var UserEmail = getRespondentEmail();
> ```

Comment: Welcome. How do you used `getRespondentEmail()`? How are you collecting the respondents email addresses?  Are you using a consumer account (free / gmail.com) or a G Suite account?

Comment: I am collecting the respondents email in a field in the form. The field was added after I enabled the "Collect email addresses" setting for the form. I am using a G Suite account; however, I do not want to have anyone log into the form as this will be on a public kiosk. Sorry I forgot to add the code for getRespondentEmail(). I am using it like so
var UserEmail = getRespondentEmail();

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [getRespondetEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getRespondentEmail()) but as a method of a FormResponse object, not as a function.

```
// Add row
var email = formResponses[i].getRespondentEmail();
```

For a complete example please take a look to my answer to [Google script to get averaged scores and emails from Google Forms (as Quiz)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47982868/1595451)

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the help!